# Any way I can set the minimumvalue and the maximumvalue in the server side for asp:RangeValidator?

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications

Does anyone know there have any way that I can set the minimumvalue and the maximumvalue in the server side for asp:RangeValidator .net c#

Example:
I have the following code, instead of hard coding the minimumvalue and the maximumvalue, any way that I can set those value during the page load?

```
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" id="rngDate" controltovalidate="txtDate" type="Date" minimumvalue="01-01-2011" maximumvalue="26-05-2011" errormessage="Please enter a valid date !" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just set the `MinimumValue` and `MaximumValue` properties in the `Page_Load`. First, change your declaration of `maximumvalue` in your sample code to `maximumvalue="05-26-2011"` (the way you have it in the sample caused an ASP.NET exception in my test). Then, just do something like this in the `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rngDate.MinimumValue = "05/01/2011";
    rngDate.MaximumValue = "05/20/2011";
}
```

It should work fine. If it's not, then maybe something else is going on in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set those properties in the Page_Load event handler:

```
rngDate.MaximumValue = "the max";
rngDate.MaximumValue = "the min";
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now, but I have something almost exactly the same on one of my websites:

```
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" id="rngDate" controltovalidate="txtDate" type="Date" minimumvalue="<%= <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %> %>" maximumvalue="<%= <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %> %>" errormessage="Please enter a valid date !" />
```

(Of course, replace `DateTime.Now` with your datetime...)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by assigning the values to `rngDate.MaximumValue` and `rngDate.MaximumValue` from your code behind

```
rngDate.MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
rngDate.MaximumValue = customDate.ToShortDateString();
```